# Failed to load file inside server with $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, include

I've been trying to get inside of my folder a url but i'm getting a error like this i've tryed with file_get_contents but isn't working anymore

```
Warning: include(/home/vol2_3/*****/*****/htdocs/new/td.php?r=8&ids=309834): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vol2_3/*****/*****/htdocs/new/test.php on line 146
```

I've been trying like this and with file_get_contents but isn't working

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/new/td.php?r=8&ids=".$info["id"]);
```

Comment: You're trying to get a local file with query parameters, which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass query string in the include() function. This function requires the PHP file path to passed, not an URL.
This will work:

```php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/new/td.php");
```